# Finding rank of augmented matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $A$ is a $4 \times 4$ matrix with rank 3 and $I$ is the $4 \times 4$ identity matrix. How can I determine the rank of the augmented matrix

$$[A\,\, I]?$$

Could the rank be 4?

From $I$ it seems that we have four independent column vectors and since they form a basis the columns of $A$ are dependent on them.  Does that argument seem right?

Answer (score 1):

you can follow  the normal approach  of finding  rank of a matrix  by reducing  it to either row reduceed  echelon  form or counting  the nonzero rows in  row reduceed  form.I prefer the last.

As you give your matrix has  rank  3 so it has 3 nonzero  rows in row reduceed  form  and since you adding a identity matrix of order $4 ×4$ it is in the  row reduceed  form always.

Now when you come at the last row you have all element   is zero of your original matrix and 1 in the  identity matrix making the whole  system  having a nonzero  fourth  row . So your answer  is   correct  and it is  4